# Pandas 'Str' object has no attribute 'to_csv'

Tags: python, pandas

At the moment, I'm wondering why is Pandas not able to convert the dataframe to a csv file as it returns `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_csv'`

I've been trying `trends.to_string(index=False).to_csv('test.csv'))` etc and a few other examples others have given, but it returns the same thing over and over.

```
def main(url):
    google = GoogleAnalysis(url)
    codes = country_codes()
    return pd.concat([
        google.trends(country_code)
        for country_code in codes[:len(codes) // 2]
    ]) 

def trends(self,country_code):
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        self._retrieve_trends(country_code),
        columns=['Title', 'Search_Score'],
    )
    df['Country Code'] = country_code
    df['Platform'] = 'Google'
    return df

if __name__ == '__main__':
    trends = main('https://trends.google.com/trends/trendingsearches/daily/rss')
    trends.to_csv('k.csv').to_string(index=False)
```

**Output of DataFrame**

```
    Title         Search_Score    Country Code     Platform        
 アジアカップ 2019     20000           JP             Google             
     康華              2000           HK             Google              
   스피릿위시          2000            KR             Google              
 Michelle Obama       50000           US             Google
```

> Updated ( Include `main` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want, the below code, you have to enter the argument of `trends` method:

```
def trends(self,country_code):
        df = pd.DataFrame(
            self._retrieve_trends(country_code),
            columns=['Title', 'Search_Score'],
        )
        df['Country Code'] = country_code
        df['Platform'] = 'Google'
        return df

if __name__ == '__main__':
    trends = main(
 'https://trends.google.com/trends/trendingsearches/daily/rss')
trends.to_csv('k.csv')
```

Comment: sorry, I didn't include the argument portion; I've updated my code.

Comment: ah jeez, I really wonder why it works now. Maybe I overlooked such a simple thing.. really feel silly

Comment: @Minial Now it works because i don't have a `to_string(index=False)` at the end, `to_csv` actually returns `None`, so there won't be a `to_string` attribute.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that. Well, thank you for your help :) I'll mark as answer once the timer is over.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import openpyxl as xls

path = r"D:\\"

with open("file.csv", "w") as file:
 for root, dirname, files in os.walk(path):
         for x in files:      
             file.write(root + "\\" + x + '\n')
             print(root + "\\" + x + '\n')
      

file.close()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).